# rspec before(:each) using factorygirl to create model not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm using rspec to test my model methods. Everything is going fine but all of a sudden factorygirl build isn't working. here's my code:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'

describe User do

  describe 'creation' do

    before(:each) do
      @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
    end

    it 'is invalid without an email address'  do
      user = @user
      user.email = nil
      user.should_not be_valid
    end

    it 'is invalid without a password' do
      user = @user
      user.password = nil
      user.should_not be_valid
    end

    it 'is invalid with an invalid email'  do
      user = @user
      user.email = "email@invalid"
      user.should_not be_valid
    end

    it 'is valid with a valid email and password'  do
      user = @user
      user.should be_valid
    end
  end

  describe "method" do

    before(:each) do
      @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
    end

    context "first_name" do

      it "should return the user's first name" do
        user = @user
        user.first_name.should == "User"
      end

    end

    context "count_of_invoices_by_year" do

      # @todo not sure how to check these since .count doesn't work
      it "should return the correct count of all invoices in the specified year" do
        # there are two invoices in 2013
        # user = @user
        # user.count_of_invoices_by_year("2013", :total).should == 2
      end

      it "should return the correct count of paid invoices in the specified year" do
        user = @user
        debugger
      end

      it "should return the correct count of sent invoices in the specified year" do

      end

    end

    context "sum_of_invoices_by_year" do

      it "should return the sum of the grand_totals of each of the invoices in the specified year" do
        # user.sum_of_invoices_by_year("2013", :total).should ==
      end

      it "should return the sum of the grand_totals of each of the paid invoices in the specified year" do

      end

      it "should return the sum of the grand_totals of each of the sent invoices in the specified year" do

      end

    end

  end

end
```

all the other @user are set correctly and work but when i get down here:

it "should return the correct count of paid invoices in the specified year" do
    user = @user
    debugger
  end

the factorygirl.build just doesn't work. I tried putting it everyone including directly in the specific test...but it just won't set to @user. what am i missing? this is the error:

```
NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method `user' for #<RSpec::Core::Example:0x007fc9ec7d4890>
```

which happens when i try to look at user because @user is nil

Comment: your code seems to be ok. Try to experiment a bit. Remove all the tests except the one that raises exception and try to run rspec. If it's not raising any more, try adding tests incrementally to figure out what is causing the problem

Comment: it's not even a test that is causing a problem. it is the factorygirl not actually creating a user properly

Comment: Obviously, it's not a FactoryGirl itself because it's used with rspec. (besides it do work in other tests, so you can assume that the reason is related with rspec)

Comment: I don't know what the cause is, but if you use `let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }` then you won't need all these extra assignments.

Comment: @AndyWaite good suggestion, thanks. however, even using let(:user) provides the same problem...it just isn't assigning to user properly

Comment: Is this code *exactly* as in your app, or did you edit it for here? I've been unable to reproduce the problem. The behaviour seems that the before block in the `method` section isn't been executed, as if there was an extra `end` somewhere which is closing that context.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out user isn't actually present in a test case unless you actually try to test something with it...which is very weird.

```
  it "should return the user's first name" do
    user.first_name.should == "User"
  end
```

this has user present but this:

```
  it "should return the user's first name" do
    debugger
  end
```

looking at the console after debugger shows user = nil here.