# RSpec before(:each) Refuses to Play Nice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

The RSpec before :each loop is really causing a problem for me, in that it doesn't seem to want to apply to each block, but only the one directly ahead of it. Here is my whole spec file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
DatabaseCleaner.clean

RSpec.describe User, :type => :model do

  describe "(1) Has Associations and Test Data" do
    context "(a) has a valid factory" do 
      it { expect(build(:user)).to be_valid }
    end

    context "(b) belongs to a company" do 
      it { expect(User.reflect_on_association(:company).macro).to eq(:belongs_to) }
    end

    context "(c) has many shifts" do 
      it { expect(User.reflect_on_association(:shifts).macro).to eq(:has_many) }
    end
  end

  describe "(2) JSON API Methods for current_user" do

    before(:each) do  
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
      @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      @schedule = FactoryGirl.create(:schedule)
      @shift = FactoryGirl.create(:shift, user_id: @user.id, schedule_id: @schedule.id)
    end

    context ".shifts returns all shifts" do
      #it { expect(@user.shifts).to eq(Shift.where(:user_id => @user.id)) }
      it { expect(@user.shifts).to include @shift }
    end

    context ".last_weeks_shifts returns all shifts for LAST week" do 
      last_weeks_schedule = FactoryGirl.create(:schedule, week_num: Date.today.cweek - 1).id
      last_weeks_shift = @shift.update_attributes(schedule_id: last_weeks_schedule)
      it { expect(@user.last_weeks_shifts).to include last_weeks_shift}
    end

    context ".this_weeks_shifts returns all shifts for THIS week" do 
      it { expect(@user.this_weeks_shifts).to equal [] }
    end

    context ".next_weeks_shifts returns all shifts for NEXT week" do 
      it { expect(@user.next_weeks_shifts).to equal [] }
    end

    context ".shift_today? returns true if it has a shift today" do 
      it { expect(@user.shift_today?).to equal true or false }
    end
  end
end
```

As a reference, specifically here is my issue:

```
before(:each) do  
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  @schedule = FactoryGirl.create(:schedule)
  @shift = FactoryGirl.create(:shift, user_id: @user.id, schedule_id: @schedule.id)
end

context ".shifts returns all shifts" do
  #it { expect(@user.shifts).to eq(Shift.where(:user_id => @user.id)) }
  it { expect(@user.shifts).to include @shift }
end

context ".last_weeks_shifts returns all shifts for LAST week" do 
  last_weeks_schedule = FactoryGirl.create(:schedule, week_num: Date.today.cweek - 1).id
  last_weeks_shift = @shift.update_attributes(schedule_id: last_weeks_schedule)
  it { expect(@user.last_weeks_shifts).to include last_weeks_shift}
end
```

If I call binding.pry and examine my objects in the last context block, here are my results:

```
[1] pry(#<Class>)> @shift
nil
[2] pry(#<Class>)> @schedule
nil
[3] pry(#<Class>)> @user
nil
```

Why are my objects that I set in a before loop disappearing? Note they ARE instance variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [rspec before(:each) using factorygirl to create model not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996213/rspec-beforeeach-using-factorygirl-to-create-model-not-working)

The instance variable representing the object isn't instantiated until you actually test it. @shift won't exist unless you test it, therefore it is much better to use let:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let(:schedule) { FactoryGirl.create(:schedule) }
let(:shift) { FactoryGirl.create(:shift, user_id: user.id, schedule_id: schedule.id) }

before(:each) do  
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

Comment: The first test passes (the one directly after the before loop) ".shifts returns all shifts", but the one immediately after it fails.

Comment: What error are you getting? Try using let outside the before block.

Comment: I did test 2/3 variables in the first test. But anyway, can you show me how use let syntax when the three variables are intertwined? @shift is a join between user/schedule, how can I add the ID of "let object" to another "let object"?